# how to get transactions number reduced with Loadrunner Controller

Tags: performance-testing, load-testing, loadrunner

On a Load Test with Loadrunner controller, I have a script which make 1029 Transactions per Hour with 1 Virtual User,with  1 "number of Iteration" ,"ignore think time", and pacing setting which start every iteration at a random interval every 3 to 4 seconds but I want to reduce the transactions to 45 Transactions per Hour. I set then the think time to "Limit think time to : 65", but without success.
Does anyone knows how to reduce the number of transactions. Is there any run time setting which must be changed to get this transactions reduced?

Comment: or shall I increase the pacing time to get transactions reduced

Comment: Do not ignore think time. Think times are used to emulate real time user interactions.

Comment: @Abhishek Asthana: it did not help

Comment: If you eliminate think time you collapse the client-server model, which is based upon a gap between requests from clients, during which the resources are free'd for use by other clients.  Your test becomes a non-predictor of performance in production as a result.   You should also define "What is a transaction?" in your context.  The term "transaction" can mean any of a half a dozen different items, from a hit to a page to a logical request which covers multiple pages to a complete business process.    Clarity will help to aid in finding a response

Comment: @James==>I mean I want to reduce the number of requests to server, which are runed with 1 Virtual user for an Hour,because I got 1029 requests per Hour, and I'd like to reduce it to 45 requests per Hour

Comment: only 45 requests per hour to a server somehow doesn't make sense..it is too low. If you really want to do it add static waits..but that again in not a realistic scenario. Maybe the question is what is the realtime scenario you are trying to automate.

Comment: The number of requests (hits) which wind up on a server can be a function of many items, including a misconfigured server and CDN for caching.   If you are hitting the business metrics but the technical metrics are way off then likely you have an issue with your cache management configuration on the server

Answer (score 2):

Use 'fixed' intervals of 80 seconds.

45 transactions per hour
3600 seconds in an hour
= 80 seconds per transaction

Comment: @Galos. Than you so much